# prevent page refresh on php form submit?

Tags: php, javascript, forms, refresh, submit

I have a page (http://qccr.dyndns.org:82/on-air-schedule) where a visitor can click a day of the week and have our radio station's schedule for that day displayed.  The only issue is that the page refreshes completely when that happens; it would be better if just the schedule in the centre of the page changed, not the whole page.  I don't really know much about javascript...is there a simple way to do that?

The relevant piece of code is here (I think):

```
    <?php



    <div class="date-input-form">
        <form action="" method="post" id="ddateform" >
            <input type="hidden" name="ddate" id="ddate" size="11" maxlength="10" value="" />
            <?php echo JHTML::_( 'form.token' ); ?>
        </form>
    </div>


    <div id="navcontainer">

    <ul id="navlist">
    <?php if($currentday=="Monday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('ddate').value = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday')); ?>'; document.getElementById('ddateform').submit();">Monday</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($currentday=="Tuesday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('ddate').value = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('tuesday')); ?>'; document.getElementById('ddateform').submit();">Tuesday</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($currentday=="Wednesday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('ddate').value = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('wednesday')); ?>'; document.getElementById('ddateform').submit();">Wednesday</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($currentday=="Thursday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('ddate').value = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('thursday')); ?>'; document.getElementById('ddateform').submit();">Thursday</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($currentday=="Friday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('ddate').value = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('friday')); ?>'; document.getElementById('ddateform').submit();">Friday</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($currentday=="Saturday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('ddate').value = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('saturday')); ?>'; document.getElementById('ddateform').submit();">Saturday</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if($currentday=="Sunday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('ddate').value = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('sunday')); ?>'; document.getElementById('ddateform').submit();">Sunday</a></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about PHP so take this with a grain of salt.

HTML forms do not refresh the page on submit by default.  Something (I'm guessing the PHP) is causing an HTML form to be generated which causes a page refresh on form submit.

I'm not sure if Barry's answer will work, but if you want to give it a try, replace the code for the Monday li with this:

**With your formatting**

```
<?php if($currentday=="Monday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('ddate').value = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday')); ?>'; document.getElementById('ddateform').submit(); return false;">Monday</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**With sane formatting**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onMondayClick(event) {
        document.getElementById('ddate').value = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday')); ?>';
        document.getElementById('ddateform').submit();
        return false;
    }
</script>

<?php if($currentday=="Monday") : ; ?>
    <li class="currentday"><?php echo $currentday; ?></li>
    <?php else : ?>
    <li><a href="#" onclick=onMondayClick>Monday</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Note that adding the line return false; to the end of a callback function is the equivalent of invoking the methods event.preventDefault() and event.stopPropagation() with event being the first argument automatically passed to callback functions.

Comment: Then you should figure out why your html form is being generated with the non-default option of automatically refreshing the page on submit.  Once you've got that, you can use PHP or a Javascript ajax call to get data from your sever, and then use Javascript to modify your page to reflect the new data.

Answer (score 0):

In whatever javascript function you call, do a `return false;` to prevent the default behavior.

```
<a onclick="dothis(); return false;" href="#">Click Me</a>
```

-or-

```
<a onclick="dothis();" href="#">Click Me</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function dothis() { /* stuff here */ return false; }
</script>
```

Learn some javascript basics, you will be well served :)

Comment: You can do this using one of many ways - you can use an `onsubmit` attribute on the `form` tag, or on the `input` tags, use `onclick` or something to that effect.

Comment: So, instead of for instance:

    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('ddate').value = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday')); ?>'; document.getElementById('ddateform').submit();">Monday</a></li>

I should add "return: false;" to the end of that, so like this?

    <li><a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('ddate').value = '<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('monday')); ?>'; document.getElementById('ddateform').submit(); return false;">Monday</a></li>

If so, I just tried it, that didn't work.

Comment: Well what you are doing is really unconventional and backwards. If you submit a form that is part of the main page, it will submit the whole page

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using jquery post function and/or with an ajax call to post the formdata